# T-SQL Optimize geographic search by longitude and latitude

Tags: algorithm, t-sql, optimization, geolocation, geocoding

What I have stored in one of my tables are geographic points in the following format:

> Longitude Latitude PostalCode

The idea is to get the closest available postal code by given longitude and latitude using the information in the table.

My algorithm work as follows:

1. Init UserLongitude and UserLatitude
2. Init StepVariable as 1.0
3. Get all records from my table where

   ```
   longitude>UserLongitude-StepVariable 
   and
   longitude<UserLongitude+StepVariable 
   and
   latitude>Userlatitude-StepVariable   
   and
   latitude<Userlatitude+StepVariable
   ```
4. If no records are found, increase StepVariable with 1.0 and  executed step 3

As I have [read](http://www.zodiacal.com/tools/lat_table.php) the longitude value for 1.0 is smaller as we move to the poles. So, my algorithm will extend the search area in not correct way when value for 1.0 for longitude and latitude are not the same.

Is there a tricky way to extend my searchable area as Square, because for now, in some place I have rectangles instead and I believe this make my search slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to calculate how many meters is the length of longitude and latitude for a specific geographic point, I use the following algorithm:

```
-- Geograpic Point Cordinates
DECLARE @LATTIDUDE REAL=45
DECLARE @LONGITUDE REAL=45
DECLARE @Distance REAL=10

-- Constants
DECLARE @ConvertionConstant AS FLOAT=2*PI()/360
DECLARE @MetersPerDegree AS FLOAT

DECLARE @LattidueInRadians AS FLOAT=@ConvertionConstant*@LATTIDUDE

DECLARE @LongitudeParameter1 AS FLOAT=111412.84
DECLARE @LongitudeParameter2 AS FLOAT=-93.5 
DECLARE @LongitudeParameter3 AS FLOAT=0.118

SET @MetersPerDegree=(@LongitudeParameter1*COS(@LattidueInRadians))+(@LongitudeParameter2*(COS(3*@LattidueInRadians)))+(@LongitudeParameter3*COS(5*@LattidueInRadians))
DECLARE @LongitudeRangeTemp AS FLOAT=@Distance/(@MetersPerDegree/1000)

-- Results for longitude
SELECT @LongitudeRangeTemp AS DegreesForGivenKM
SELECT @MetersPerDegree    AS MetersPerDegreeOfLongitude

-- Constants
DECLARE @LatitudeParameter1 AS FLOAT=111132.92
DECLARE @LatitudeParameter2 AS FLOAT=-559.82
DECLARE @LatitudeParameter3 AS FLOAT=1.175
DECLARE @LatitudeParameter4 AS FLOAT=-0.0023

-- Results for longitude
SET @MetersPerDegree=(@LatitudeParameter1+(@LatitudeParameter2*COS(2*@LattidueInRadians))+(@LatitudeParameter3*COS(4*@LattidueInRadians))+(@LatitudeParameter4*COS(6*@LattidueInRadians)))
DECLARE @LatitudeRangeTemp AS FLOAT=@Distance/(@MetersPerDegree/1000)
SELECT @LatitudeRangeTemp AS  DegreesForGivenKM
SELECT @MetersPerDegree   AS  MetersPerDegreeOfLatitude
```

An additional parameter is added for kilometers - the code will calculate how many degrees are  are equal to the given kilometers.

You are free to implement the code in function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `Geography` and `Geometry` data types and their associated functions (eg: `STDistance`)

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933917(v=sql.100).aspx

If you can't do that, then the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is useful for calculating distances

Comment: I do not think I can use STDistance because it  gives the shortest distance between two objects. I need a better way to maintain my StepVariable - to increase/decrease with different value for longitude  base on current UserLongitude value.

Comment: @gotqn It seems you're after the shortest distance - use STDistance to calculate them all, and take the smallest.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but using only this function, means I first should calculate the distance between my point and all of the others points, and then to get the shortest one. I have about 3 millions of records and I think this will be slow. That's why, I want to get only the points around the new one, but sometimes there are no other points in the rectangle I have created around the new point and I am making a larger one. What I want is not to create rectangle, but Square - the rectangle is a result of the different values of longitude.